# Difference between 2 ways of defining components in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I came accross 2 ways of declaring components in ReactJs. What is the different as both seem to work fine!

**Case I:**

```
function Roger(props){
    return <h1>Hello! {props.name},{props.message}</h1>;
}
```

**Case II:**

```
var Roger = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1>Hello! {props.name},{props.message}</h1>
    );
  }
});
```

Can anyone help me out in understanding difference?

Comment: Check the stackoverflow doc for more detail on `Stateless Functional Component`, it will cove all the points in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/reactjs/6588/stateless-functional-components#t=201704200855545376703

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case I is creating Stateless Functional Components, as a rule of thumb it's recommended to use it whenever possible. Case II is useful for example if you need to use `this` or if you need life-cycle methods.

Check this great post to learn more: http://jamesknelson.com/should-i-use-react-createclass-es6-classes-or-stateless-functional-components/

From the official docs:

> The simplest way to define a component
>   is to write a JavaScript function:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}
```

> This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single
>   "props" object argument with data and returns a React element. We call
>   such components "functional" because they are literally JavaScript
>   functions.
>
> You can also use an ES6 class to define a component:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;   
  } 
}
```

> The above two components are equivalent from React's point of view.
>
> Classes have some additional features that we will discuss in the next
>   sections. Until then, we will use functional components for their
>   conciseness.
>
> source: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components